# Turn on cell editing with a single-click instead of a double-click

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

is there any way to enable editing for a cell on the first mouse click in that cell, rather than requiring a double-click? I've set `editable: true`, but I can't see any options for custom properties to modify what triggers this, nor can I find an applicable event.

I'm using the React version of ag-grid-enterprise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a grid option (not a column option), singleClickEdit, which you can set to 'true'. The default is false.